# Godot: 'is_on_floor' problem

Tags: collision-detection, loading, godot

I have a character in a basic platformer game and am having trouble.

Whenever my character stands over two tiles on a tilemap and appears to be directly colliding with them the character's *is_on_floor* variable toggles constantly between true and false, messing with my jump physics. Standing on a non-tilemap object.

My collisions have been checked and are fitted to each object. my tiles are at a 24 * 25 in size.

**edit**

I have recently been working with sloping tiles and have encountered a similar problem after having changed my collision box into a capsule.

How do I fix this and what is causing this?

Comment: I usually end up using a raycast pointing down for that. It's also useful for having a better control over when the character can jump when near a platform border.

Comment: @Logain Sounds good I might try that if I can't find anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Switch to 3.1**

The problem seems to be fixed in 3.1